# XAML Hub Control Windows 8.1 Universal, InvokeCommandAction not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I have a hub control on my main page and in the HubSection header i cant get the element to fire when i click on the button, however when i move the XAML into the DataTemplate the event if fired. Can you please explain to me why this is, do i need to enable something in the HubSection.Header so that the event can fire?

here is the code that doesn't fire:

```
 <HubSection >
                <HubSection.Header>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <TextBlock                            
                            Text="{Binding
                                WhatToWatch.Name,
                                Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction
                                    Command="{Binding ViewMoreCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding WhatToWatch.Name}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HubSection.Header>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:RowGridView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding
                            WhatToWatch.Data,
                            Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

And here is the code that does fire the Event:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel    > 
                        <StackPanel >
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewMoreCommand}" />
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <TextBlock 
                                Text="{Binding
                                    WhatToWatch.Name,
                                    Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <controls:RowGridView 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding
                                WhatToWatch.Data,
                                Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

Its the same code, but in the second one the core:InvokeCommandAction action is in the DataTemplate, is this what allows the XAML to call the event? why is this so?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the stackpanel responding versus the datatemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a reference to your page that owns the ViewModel.

Set a name for your page for example: "pageRoot"
then change your Behavior to

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewMoreCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```